microk8s pods not starting, containerd possible conflict
a few days ago I had to install microk8s to try out a project, all seems great and stuff but pods never start.. and I wonder why, here is what I found so far:
I use ubuntu 22.04 LTS, previously I had docker and minikube installed and working on this box.
During the debugging process, I noticed that I have some services doubled, like:
$ sudo systemctl | grep containerd
  containerd.service                                                                                       loaded active running   containerd container runtime
  snap.microk8s.daemon-containerd.service                                                                  loaded active running   Service for snap application microk8s.daemon-containerd

I think this one is crucial, we'll get back to it later.
in the logs of snap.microk8s.daemon-kubelite.service, I found that it is constantly restarting, because of:
microk8s.daemon-kubelite[3059551]: F0619 19:29:37.362667 3059551 daemon.go:57] Kubelet exited failed to run Kubelet: validate service connection: validate CRI v1 runtime API for endpoint "/var/snap/microk8s/common/run/containerd.sock": rpc error: code = Unimplemented desc = unknown service runtime.v1.RuntimeService

I found this thread, pointing to a problem with containerd
In the logs of snap.microk8s.daemon-containerd.service, I found this:
Jun 19 10:08:09 gg-virtual-machine microk8s.daemon-containerd[1308210]: time="2024-06-19T10:08:09.447990187+03:00" level=warning msg="failed to load plugin io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri" error="invalid plugin config: `default_runtime_name` is empty"
Jun 19 10:08:09 gg-virtual-machine microk8s.daemon-containerd[1308210]: time="2024-06-19T10:08:09.448751097+03:00" level=info msg=serving... address="127.0.0.1:1338"

1 - could it be that condtainerd, coming with the microk8s installation is in some sort of conflict with containerd installed on the system previously? If yes - what's the best option to go?
2 - if it is not the suspected conflict, what could the problem possibly be?
